# Cassandra Presto synchronization issue

Tags: cassandra, data-synchronization, presto

We have been using Cassandra in our current live project for almost a year. We are using Cassandra 2.1.14 and sometimes we get to see that there is some synchronization problem between Cassandra and Presto. When there is some update in database using Cassandra and I am going to fire any query from presto then it doesn’t return data while data exists in the database.

Second issue is that sometimes delete and update statements don’t get executed. It shows no error but transaction is not committed.

Comment: Are you able to set up Cassandra and Presto on a laptop to demonstrate the sync issue? How does the issue manifest itself? Are there any logs that might point to the problem? This is completely unreproducible for readers at present, so please do as much debugging as you can and represent your findings in this question.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata caching in Cassandra doesn't update immediately, which means you might not see some changes. I suggest you change `cassandra.schema-cache-ttl` to 0s; we're going to remove caching in Cassandra altogether soon.

Comment: i made this change in the required file cassandra.schema-cache-ttl=0 and restarted the presto. when i run any query it shows no worker node available.

Comment: That is a separate issue -- make sure that the worker nodes are actually started and that you deployed the Cassandra config to all of the nodes and restarted on all the nodes.

Comment: i did same as you said. I made changes in cassandra.properties file kept in catalina folder of presto and restarted the presto query engine. when i tried to execute any query then it shown no worker node available

Comment: thanks for your continuous support. i couldn't see any error in system.log file of cassandra but when i restarted the presto after making changes in configuration file then it shown error like 'no worker node available'

Comment: It would be an error on the Presto worker -- in log.properties. If you install Presto via the tarball, it would be located in the etc directory of the install; if you install Presto via the RPM, it would be located in /var/log/presto/server.log.

Comment: can you please tell me which presto version is best suitable for cassandra3.10?

Comment: You should use the most recent version of Presto, it works with Cassandra 3.x

Comment: Ok. i have created a new testing machine with cassandra 3.1.14 and presto 0.174. Now i check it with new machine.